# openssl crypt/decrypt from ubuntu 16.04 to Centos 7.3 OK, but not from ubuntu 18.04 to Centos 7.3

Tags: openssl

I am encrypting a file to transfert it from an ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 host to a Centos 7.3 host.

I encrypt like that :

```
openssl des3 -e -kfile MY_SYMETRIC_KEY_FILE -in FILE_TO_BE_CRYPTED -out CRYPTED_FILE
```

And decrypt like that :

```
openssl des3 -d -kfile MY_SYMETRIC_KEY_FILE -in CRYPTED_FILE -out UNCRYPTED_FILE
```

openssl versions I have :

```
Ubuntu 16.04 : 1.0.2g
Centos 7.3 : 1.0.1e
Ubuntu 18.04 : 1.1.0g
```

Encrypt from Ubuntu 16.04, decrypt on an Ubuntu 16.04 : it is OK

Encrypt from Ubuntu 16.04, decrypt on a Centos 7.3 : it is OK

Encrypt from Ubuntu 18.04, decrypt on an Ubuntu 18.04 : it is OK

But When I encrypt from Ubuntu 18.04 and Decrypt on a Centos 7.3 : I get this error :

```
bad decrypt
140503464642464:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:604:
```

Why ? How can I get solve that ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1067762/75668

Comment: bad decrypt messages are usually caused by incompatibilies between OpenSSL. Please check if this works if you specify -md flag when encrypting:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304570/how-to-resolve-the-evp-decryptfinal-ex-bad-decrypt-during-file-decryption

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by using this encryption command :

```
openssl des3 -e -md md5 -kfile MY_SYMETRIC_KEY_FILE -in FILE_TO_BE_CRYPTED -out CRYPTED_FILE
```

(Added -md md5 option)